# Pi3 A+ not boot from EMMC

Tags: boot-issues

I bought a generic "EMMC module" meant for Nano Pi.

[image]

To be honest it was a trial to see if I can use it as general memory and boot from it with the attached SD module.

The image to it was written from RPi Imager, with first RPi OS 64bit, then 32bit lite.

However, while it was starting, there is no other function than 4 short green LED blinks which means some start*elf file is not found. I remember Rpi is doing some disk magic when it has fresh new media, however, it did not seem so as there was no other LED activity.

The image seems to be written correctly, I see files in windows.

Is it even possible to boot from such modules? Any ideas on how to make it work?

At first, I thought I bricked it, but I was able to boot from the old SD card. I thought it would work like a normal SD card, but guess I am wrong...

Comment: I take it that eMMC is sitting on some sort of "adapter" and you plug it in the sd slot on the pi

Comment: I am plugging what you can see on picture straight into pi SD card slot. I also tried booting from Emmc via USB SD reader but with no luck either.

Comment: If you boot from regular SD - can you read the eMMC on the USB SD Reader?